# Update data type from integer to decimal128 for all document having nest array in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, json, mongodb-3.2, mongodb-4.0

Had a JSON structure which is having nested array and need to update all data type for that json structure

```
[
  {
    student: [
      {
        name: {
          firstName: "Rahul",
          lastName: "khurana",
          Address: "xyz"
        },
        mark: [
          {
            maths: 19,
            english: 10,
            science: 20
          }
        ],
        subject: {
          subjectName: "Maths",
          subjectCode: 1
        }
      },
      {
        name: {
          firstName: "Shahrukh",
          lastName: "khan",
          Address: "xyz"
        },
        mark: [
          {
            maths: 45,
            english: 70,
            science: 100
          }
        ],
        subject: {
          subjectName: "Maths",
          subjectCode: 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

need to update maths datatype from integer to decimal128
tried  query for updating data

```
db.test.updateMany({},
   [
      {
         $set: {
            
            phone: {
               $map: {
                  input: "$phone",
                  as:"p",
          in:{address:{$map:{input:"$$p.phone",in:{$mergeObjects:["$this",{telephone:{$toDecimal:"$$this.telephone"}}]}}}}
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Phone numbers are neither integers nor decimal numbers; they are strings and should be treated as such.

Comment: this just a example json

Comment: That's not a valid JSON document. Please provide valid sample data (maybe at https://mongoplayground.net/). Otherwise it's difficult to provide a working solution.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/32815/wernfried-domscheit update the json can you check now

Comment: thanks guys got the solution I just missing (name:"$$s.name" & subject:"$$s.subject" ) this things

Answer (score 0):

working with this query,
thanks

```
db.test.updateMany({},
   [
      {
         $set: {
            
            student: {
               $map: {
                  input: "$student",
                  as:"s",
          in:{name:"$$s.name",mark:{$map:{input:"$$s.mark",in:{$mergeObjects:["$$this",{maths:{$toDecimal:"$$this.maths"}}]}}},subject:"$$s.subject"}
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
)
```